# What are the products of each categories fewest requested by customers? NorthwindDB

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I have tried to solve that question and i got to this

```
SELECT 
    c.CategoryID, p.ProductID,p.ProductName, COUNT(OrderID) TotalV 
FROM 
    [Order Details] od
INNER JOIN 
    Products p ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
INNER JOIN 
    Categories c ON c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         t.CategoryID, MIN(TotalV) MinV 
     FROM
         (SELECT 
              Categories.CategoryID, Products.ProductID, 
              COUNT(OrderID) TotalV 
          FROM 
              [Order Details]
          JOIN 
              Products ON [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID
          JOIN 
              Categories ON Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID
          GROUP BY 
              Products.ProductID, Categories.CategoryID) t
    GROUP BY 
        t.CategoryID) n ON c.CategoryID = n.CategoryID
GROUP BY 
    c.CategoryID, p.ProductID, MinV, p.ProductName
HAVING 
    COUNT(OrderID) = MinV
```

Results :

```
CategoryID | ProductID |        ProductName         | TotalV
-----------| ----------| ---------------------------| ------ 
1          | 67        | Laughing Lumberjack Lager  | 10     
2          | 15        | Genen Shouyu               | 6
3          | 48        | Chocolade                  | 6
.            .                   .                     .
.            .                   .                     .
.            .                   .                     .
```

I'm not sure if that is a good way because I'm using twice this:

```
SELECT 
    Categories.CategoryID,Products.ProductID, COUNT(OrderID) TotalV 
FROM 
    [Order Details]
JOIN 
    Products ON [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID
JOIN 
    Categories ON Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID
GROUP BY 
    Products.ProductID, Categories.CategoryID
```

So I think there could be a better way to perform that question, any help?